# List binary packages with brew

Tags: homebrew

How can I list packages that are not built from source? aka the bottle packages.

Any ideas?

I also tried commands like `find /usr/local/homebrew/ -iname bottle*`, and it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like brew supports JSON output, so the following command would do it.

```
brew info --json=v1 --installed | jq -r '.[] | if .installed[0].poured_from_bottle then .name else empty end'
```